# Adding an Array of Objects with some new properties to another Array of Objects which has same name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, logic, redux-toolkit

I have an array of Objects called "value" in my redux store which I'm newly creating by adding start time/end time to it every time the process starts & stops. looks like this

```
const value = [
{startTime:1635926165, name:"dailyScripts", endTime:1635926189},
{startTime:1635926125, name:"datawarehouse", endTime:1635926125},
{startTime:1234567890, name:"dummp", endTime:1234567890}
]
```

I have another array of objects in a "local state" called list which has all the data. Here I want to add the start time and end time to each obj that has the same name as above.

```
const list = [
{pid: 248, name: 'dailyScripts', pm2_env: {…}, pm_id: 2, monit: {…}}
{pid: 259, name: 'datawarehouse', pm2_env: {…}, pm_id: 2, monit: {…}}
{pid: 0, name: 'dump', pm2_env: {…}, pm_id: 2, monit: {…}}
]
```

so my final output should look like this -

```
const list = [
{pid: 248, name: 'dailyScripts',...otherObjs, startTime:1635926165, endTime:1635926189}
{pid: 259, name: 'datawarehouse',...otherObjs, startTime:1635926125, endTime:1635926125}
{pid: 0, name: 'dump',...otherObjs, startTime:1635926165, endTime:1635926189}
]
```

How do I go about it with React? I want to mutate the list state or merge the value arr with the list arr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```js
    const value = [
      { startTime: 1635926165, name: "dailyScripts", endTime: 1635926189 },
      { startTime: 1635926125, name: "datawarehouse", endTime: 1635926125 },
      { startTime: 1234567890, name: "dummp", endTime: 1234567890 }
    ];
    const list = [
      { pid: 248, name: 'dailyScripts', pm2_env: {}, pm_id: 2, monit: {} },
      { pid: 259, name: 'datawarehouse', pm2_env: {}, pm_id: 2, monit: {} },
      { pid: 0, name: 'dump', pm2_env: {}, pm_id: 2, monit: {} }
    ];
    let output = [];
    list.forEach(e => {
      let valueTime = value.find(ee => ee.name === e.name);
      if (valueTime) {
        output.push({...e, startTime : valueTime.startTime, endTime : valueTime.endTime });
      } else {
        output.push({...e});
      }
    });
    console.log(output);
```

Comment: your code is proper but i'm getting this error - typeError: Cannot add property startTime, object is not extensible
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/akii/Desktop/redux-pm2-v1/pm2-admin-webapp/src/components/Layout/PM2StatusData.js:75
  72 | mutatedStatusList.forEach(e => {
  73 |   let valueTime = timeList.find(ee => ee.name === e.name);
  74 |   if (valueTime) {
> 75 |     e.startTime = valueTime.startTime;
     | ^  76 |     e.endTime = valueTime.endTime;
  77 |   }
  78 | });

Comment: yes, it works! thank you. I realized when I read more about it that you have to do a deep copy of the entire obj.